# Creating border around ImageIcon on a JLabel, not around the Jlabel

Tags: java, swing, border, jlabel

[image]

I have problem with creating border for an icon in JLabel. I have JPanel in which I set it into GridLayout. I added Jlabel on the JPanel. The size of the JLabel were according to the size of the icon. However when I tried to set the border on the icon, it created border according to the size of the grid and not the size of the icon inside the grid.

How can I create a border around the image not on the size of the grid?

**Why the border followed the size of the grid and not the size of the imageIcon?**

```
JPanel panel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS,COLS,2,2)); 
panel.setsize(600,600);

....
JLabel = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.LEFT);
label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
...
label.setborder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED,5));
panel.add(label);
```

Comment: Answer already given when this question was originally posted on Nov 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083389/how-to-create-border-around-an-image-and-not-on-around-the-jlabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Thanks to this site http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=5785467�

```
Image image = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(widthX,heightY, image.SCALE_SMOOTH);            
icon.setImage(image);   

int borderWidth = 1;
int spaceAroundIcon = 0;
Color borderColor = Color.BLUE;

BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth() + (2 * borderWidth + 2 * spaceAroundIcon),icon.getIconHeight() + (2 * borderWidth + 2 * spaceAroundIcon), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
g.setColor(borderColor);
g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), borderWidth + spaceAroundIcon, borderWidth + spaceAroundIcon, null);

BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(5); //5 pixels wide (thickness of the border)
g.setStroke(stroke);

g.drawRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth() - 1, bi.getHeight() - 1);
g.dispose();

label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi), JLabel.LEFT);
label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);      

panel.add(label);
```

Comment: I've added 2 lines of code to your original code to make it work, you used 6 times more :)

Comment: Thank you tulskiy :) ... I found this codes fit the requirement of my program, if I used Flowlayout I need to change my code a lot (overall), so I preferred this one than Flowlayout :)

Answer (score -2):

Add your label to a panel with FlowLayout, and add the panel to the GridLayout panel.

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway that I don't have to use so many panel?

Comment: You where given the exact same answer on Nov 3 when you first posted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083389/how-to-create-border-around-an-image-and-not-on-around-the-jlabel, You just wasted tulskiy time by reposting the same question. There are other approaches, but I'm not about to waste my time since you ignored my original suggestion 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @Jessy: you can customize JLabel paint method, but it would be harder. Just write some simple helper method that wraps JLabel in a panel.

Comment: -1, for suggesting to customize the JLabel paint method. There are far easier approaches.

Comment: @camickr: funny, it's the second time you downvote me on an answer for a question you answered before in a duplicate :) And I wasn't suggesting him to customize the JLabel, I was showing him that searching for an alternative method might be a waste of time.

Comment: @tulskiy: Thanks, I'll stick to your suggestion :)

Comment: @Jessy, so why is this answer any better now than it was 3 weeks ago? Why did you ignore the other posting which has a much better answer?

Comment: @tulskiy, I don't keep track of who I upvote/downvote. Voting is done based on the merit of the answer. Although I do remember posters who tend to ignore advice or not bother to accept answers. Jessy is this type of poster so I don't go out of my way to help until they start showing the same respect.